# EnumSet parcelable

Tags: java, android, serialization, parcelable, enumset

I'm writting the `writeToParcel` method and my model has an `EnumSet<object>` as attribut. I don't know which `out.write....()` i have to use for this type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EnumSet implements `Serializable` hence you can use `out.writeSerializable(enumset)`

Comment: Add a cast ot EnumSet --> `EnumSet<enum> read = (EnumSet<enum>) in.readSerializable()`